# Django CMS show_menu includes pages of other languages

Tags: django, django-cms

Our Django CMS website has multiple languages. We have some pages that are not translated in all languages (see picture below). In the languages that don't have those pages, the menu shows those pages anyway (see picture below).

I would expect that if a page doesn't have a specific translation, it doesn't get shown in the menu. I am not sure if this is a Django CMS bug or if I am missing something.

How do I get `show_menu` to show only pages that have translations?

For better representation:

Our pages (note that in first section only `Email tester` has english translation):
[image: Our Pages]

This is the rendered english menu, but all the pages are shown. I would expect to see only `Email Tester`:
[image: Rendered menu]

Answer (score 0):

I realized it was just a matter of the `CMS_LANGUAGES` setting in `settings.py`. [Django CMS documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/3.2.3/reference/configuration.html#cms-languages)

From the documentation:

```
CMS_LANGUAGES = {
1: [
    {
        'code': 'en',
        'name': gettext('English'),
        'fallbacks': ['de', 'fr'],
        'public': True,
        'hide_untranslated': True,
        'redirect_on_fallback':False,
    },
    {
        'code': 'de',
        'name': gettext('Deutsch'),
        'fallbacks': ['en', 'fr'],
        'public': True,
    }
],
'default': {
    'fallbacks': ['en', 'de'],
    'redirect_on_fallback':True,
    'public': True,
    'hide_untranslated': False,
}
```

}

The setting `'hide_untranslated'` controls whether the translations will be shown in the menu or not.

Setting it to `True` solved my problem.